# Couchbase: Index to find binary documents

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase instane where we loaded a bunch of documents that ended up being binary documents instead of json (by accident). For whatever reason, we are not able to create a primary index on the database (enterprise restrictions, not couchbase error). I need to figure out how to delete all of these binary documents. If I can query them, I can delete them. But I can't query them without an index. Does anyone know how you could create an index (not a primary index) that would let you query and therefore delete all of the binary documents?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming not every document in the bucket is binary, otherwise you could just flush or delete the bucket.

I think primary index is your best bet. I'm not sure why it's a restriction for you, but maybe just temporarily create it?

But another thing you could try is creating a Map/Reduce View that is somehow able to determine if a document is binary or not (maybe just based on the key?). Then, you could write a program that queries the map/reduce view for the keys, and delete the documents by key.